# Skipping blank lines with strpos in PHP

Tags: php

I want to read a line and if it is blank, skip it. It seems to work but the text file I'm reading begins with three blank lines and it only skips one of them. How can I make it skip all three blank lines at the beginning of the file as well as all other blank lines throughout the file?

```
$handle = fopen("testlog.log", "r");
if ($handle) {
   while (!feof($handle)) {
      $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
      $pos = strpos( $buffer, '/n' );
      if ($pos == false) {
         //do stuff
   }
}
```

### Edit

Here's the full code. I know I'm doing something wrong...

There are multiple delimiters in the log file, is there a way to condense the variables?

Log file: http://www.castleotwonline.com/crawlerlogs/testlog.log

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("testlog.log", "r");

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 
mysql_select_db("castleot_crawlerlogs",$conn);

    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer0 = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer1 = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer2 = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer3 = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer4 = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer5 = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $pos = strpos( $buffer, '\n' );
            if ($pos === false) {
                list($version,$versiondata)=explode(" : ",$buffer0);
                list($board,$boarddata)=explode(" --- ",$buffer1);
                list($abilityfriend,$abfdata)=explode(" : ",$buffer2);
                list($abilityenemy,$abedata)=explode(" : ",$buffer3);
                list($mana,$manadata)=explode(" : ",$buffer4);
                list($secret,$secretdata)=explode(": ",$buffer5);
                $secret = "Enemy_secret";
                $sql = "INSERT INTO logtest ($version,$board,$abilityfriend,$abilityenemy,$mana,$secret) VALUES('".$versiondata."','".$boarddata."','".$abfdata."','".$abedata."','".$manadata."','".$secretdata."')";   

                echo $version." : ".$versiondata."<br>".$board." : ".$boarddata."<br>".$abilityfriend." : ".$abfdata."<br>".$abilityenemy." : ".$abedata."<br>".$mana." : ".$manadata."<br>".$secret." : ".$secretdata."<br>";

                mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
else {
    echo "File load failed.";
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: every *line* will have a break at its end, so your check makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$handle = fopen("testlog.log", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        if (!empty($buffer) && $buffer[0] !== "\n") {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```